# Verifying salted hashes with Perls unpack()

Tags: perl, hash, passwords, unpack

I'm trying to verify salted passwords with Perl and am stuck with unpack.

I've got a salted hashed password, e.g. for SHA256: SSHA256 = SHA256('password' + 'salt') + 'salt'
Base64 encoded that gets '
{SSHA256}eje4XIkY6sGakInA+loqtNzj+QUo3N7sEIsj3fNge5lzYWx0'.

I store this string in my user database. When a user logs in need to separate the salt from the hash to hash the supplied password with the salt and compare the result to the one retrieved from the db. This is where I'm stuck. I don't seem to have the right unpack template separate the hash (8-bit binary, fixed length, in this case 32 byte) from the salt (8-bit binary, variable length).

I have tried something like
`my ($hash, $salt) = unpack('N32 N*', $data);`
but that doesn't seem to work out.

My question is: How can I unpack this hash (after it has been Base64 decoded) to get the fixed length hash in one and the variable length salt in another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the whole picture is present, but the `unpack` template you have specified -`'N32 N*'`- is for 32 *unsigned long* (32-bit) (big-endian) integers ([see pack docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)).

Looks like you may instead need unsigned chars: `'32C C*'`

Comment: Thanks, in the end this led to my solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're needlessly re-inventing the wheel.

You could use e.g. [Crypt::SaltedHash](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SaltedHash) to easily verify it, for instance:

```
my $password_entered = $cgi->param('password');
my $valid = Crypt::SaltedHash->validate($salted, $password_entered);
```

A longer example, showing using Crypt::SaltedHash to generate the salted password in the first instance, too:

```
my $csh = Crypt::SaltedHash->new(algorithm => 'SHA-256');
$csh->add('secretpassword');
my $salted =  $csh->generate;
# $salted will contain the salted hash (Crypt::SaltedHash picks random
# salt for you automatically)

# for example:
  DB x $salted = $csh->generate;
0  '{SSHA256}H1WaxHcyAB81iyIPwib/cCUtjqCm2sxQNA1QvGeh/iT3m51w'

# validating that against the plaintext 'secretpassword' shows it's right:
  DB x Crypt::SaltedHash->validate($salted, 'secretpassword');
0  1

# and trying it with an incorrect password:
  DB x Crypt::SaltedHash->validate($salted, 'wrongpassword');
0  ''
```

No reason to re-invent all of this yourself.

Comment: This module doesn't do what needs to be done in my case, but in general it is probably worth a second look.

Comment: It doesn't help you separate the salt from the salted hashed password, no, but as I said, I think you'd be better off letting Crypt::SaltedHash take care of comparing hashed passwords for you. It's tried and tested, and  people re-inventing security-related code always makes me nervous :)  However, as always TIMTOWDI!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing RFC2307 the hard way and also manage to introduce bugs. Those `+` do not mean what you think.

Subclass [Authen::Passphrase::SaltedDigest](http://p3rl.org/Authen%3a%3aPassphrase%3a%3aSaltedDigest) instead.